# How to add Android Studio to the launcher?

Tags: command-line, launcher, android

I'm trying to install Android Studio so that I can launch it from a launcher instead of via terminal.

**Android Studio > Tools > Create Desktop Entry** doesn't do anything

Can someone give specific instructions please?

I think this is something to do with the permissions in `/usr/local/` I tried doing a `chmod` as explained in [this article](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/create-application-launcher-add-icon-to-unity-ubuntu-12-10/) and it still didn't work.

I tried modifying the Android Studio launcher file that was in `/usr/share/applications/` and it would not launch the app under my user. If I launch it as root it's fine, but that's not very practical.

Comment: What do you want to do finally? An icon to launch it, or alias? I personally recommend to do both options. You should read [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/62483) to add the commands to your PATH.

Comment: If some answer has been useful for you, please upvote it and [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer). So your question remains as *answered*. Thanks

Comment: None of the answers have helped, I have spent the past two and a half hours trying to do this with no luck; I'm completely befuddled

Comment: What you didn't mentioned specifically what do you want to have as a result. I've added the android tools to my PATH and created an Icon on my desktop with the answer of @Shah. So if you have a *new problem* you should tell us *what is that problem*, otherwise, accept an answer.

Comment: I have the file in usr/local the solution given is for /home/programs/ there be different permissions there. Unable to locate suitable startup script in '/home/user/programs/androidstudio/android-studio/bin'.

Comment: If so add replace that path with your (`/usr/local.. blahblahblah`) My recommendation is put the whole package in a new folder on your home directory called `bin`, then `$HOME/bin/android`

Comment: For me logging out and logging in was needed for it to appear.

Comment: In most cases the menu entry point for doing this is not immediately visible. And so the instructions found almost anywhere are missing the crucial step:

You have to make a project first and then choose it. Then you have access to the "Create Desktop Entry" facility.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Here is my AndroidStudio .desktop file which works from the launcher.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec="/home/username/Programs/AndroidStudio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/home/username/Programs/AndroidStudio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
Name[en_GB]=android-studio.desktop
```

If you are unable to create an entry for Android Studio on the Unity launcher through the *Tools > Create Desktop Entry...* option, it is possible that you might have a Unity generated `jetbrains-android-studio.desktop` in your `~/.local/share/applications` folder. To confirm, open the file and check for the following entry:

```
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Delete the file and try again.

---

Alternatively, you can also open Android Studio, click on *Configure* -> *Create Desktop Entry*. This should create an entry on the dash:

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Could you explain further the value of the `Exec` property?

Comment: Yeah your alternate note was what I tried and got the message I have posted in the main post. The .desktop file I can Google how to create that, right?

Comment: It is easiest to do the "alternate". From the Android Studio welcome screen just click "Configure" and then "Create Desktop Entry".  Then you can search in Dash and Lock to Launcher.

Comment: somehow, both methods not working for 14.04...

Comment: @Lucio I don't have any experience with Ubuntu, but it looks (and sounds) like that is the location of the executable/runnable/binary/program/whatever it is called in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to confirm it works in my Linux distro Ubuntu 14.10 LTS

Comment: Great, this works. (Y)

Comment: This is now under *Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...*

Comment: Great, it's working on Linux Mint

Comment: The icon is now called studio.png

Answer (score 316):

```
Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry
```

[image]

Now, you should be able to see in your system menu:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is pretty simple. Thank u so much!

Comment: thank you... its so simple to do... you saved my time...

Comment: This didn't work when I marked 'create desktop entry for all users'. Unchecking this option, the shortcut remained alive after reboot

Comment: FYI, it also works in ElementaryOS, which is also an Ubuntu-based distro.

Comment: It doesn't get easier. Super helpful.

Comment: Wow! How old is this feature? Never noticed about it, thanks!

Comment: Greate its so simple

Comment: This should be the accepted answer due to simplicity

Answer (score 17):

You can open Android Studio, click on Configure -> Create Desktop Entry. This should create an entry on the dash.

Comment: While the accepted answer is quite valid and could be adapted for other applications, this is the simplest way to create an entry.

Comment: But it requires setting up path variable so you should explicitly mention it in your answer

Comment: Is not `Configure` but `Tools` instead.

Answer (score 10):

From the quick start panel, (which opens up once android-studio IDE launched), click on "Configure" which takes you to the configure panel then click on "Create Desktop Entry".

You can also go to Tools -> Create Desktop Entry once you're inside an Android Studio Project.

This basically puts a `jetbrains-android-studio.desktop` file into your Ubuntu's `~/.local/share/applications` folder.

Comment: simple and elegant , tank you...

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Right-click its icon in the launcher.
3. "Lock to Launcher".

Comment: Your answer while possible may be a bit late as the OP already accepted the other answer. Your help is of course appreciated, however you might be better served by focusing your efforts on the [unanswered questions](//askubuntu.com/unanswered)

Comment: Dosn't work on Ubuntu 17 for some reason. The "lock to launcher" doesn't show.

Comment: Effective on 16.04 + Android Studio 3.5.3

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know of doing this is, open Android Studio then under Tools click on "Create Desktop Entry". This will list android studio in all programs list, from there you can add the application to quick launch.

Answer (score 2):

Android studio does not seem to have this option to '*Create a desktop entry*' anymore, so I decided to switch to using [snaps](https://snapcraft.io).

I was able to install android studion using this snap:

https://github.com/snapcrafters/android-studio

The install command is listed on the github link, but here it is anyways:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

This will install and manage any updates for android studio, as well as add a desktop entry!

---

*If you are interested in having something like this for some JetBrains IDE's, then checkout [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/)!*

Comment: This question is five years old, I doubt any of it is relevant still - thanks for your contribution though @smac89 

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 1.2+ the WM_CLASS is jetbrains-studio. So you have to add or change

```
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

to your android-studio.desktop file.

Comment: Suggest an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/298864/edit), please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this changing android-studio from /usr/local/ to /opt/
Then I configured using the tools menu
Android studio 4.1.3