# DESKTOP FILE: android studio installation on 14.04

Tags: command-line, android-studio, ubuntu-for-android

TO Create a new file androidstudio.desktop, I have run "nano ~/.local/share/applications/adndroidstudio.desktop" in my terminal
,then i added 
"[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec="/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=android-studio"

then i pressed "CTRL+X" >>"Y">>ENTER.
after then what shoud i do?help me I hooked up with this for 3 hours!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Android Studio to the launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298857/how-to-add-android-studio-to-the-launcher)

Comment: my question is not anwered!!please help with details as i am new to ubuntu!!the same code it has been shown!! but what should I do with that ? mean where to put it or write it? as i have said putting it in my terminal ,after pressing "CTRL+X" ,then "Y" and then 'ENTER'.it shows no error in terminal. but after what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to manually create the desktop file. First delete any files you already created.

- Open Android Studio.
- Then click on `Tools` -> `Create desktop Entry`
  in the menu bar.

Comment: thanx !your answer is so clear!!