# Replace Android studio 1.5 launcher shortcut with Android studio 2.0 shortcut

Tags: launcher, shortcuts, android-studio

I used Android studio for a long time. I like to have it on launcher, so I run studio.sh in terminal, and when AS running, I lock the icon to Launcher so I can run it with one click later. Now I have Android studio 2 extracted in another folder. I unlocked the Android studio 1.5 shortcut from launcher, run the version 2 of Android studio and lock it to launcher. But when I close the windows, click to the icon, its open the Android studio 1.5 instead of the version 2.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove older version Android Studio, it should also delete this misleading launcher. Then try to create AndroidStudio2.0 launcher using one of available here methods: [How to add Android Studio to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298857/how-to-add-android-studio-to-the-launcher)

Comment: I used to like to keep both version. So I didn't remove version 1.5. But now removing version 1.5 is Ok with me