# Why android studio is not working from dock and my applications?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-for-android, android-sdk

Yesterday, I installed Android Studio and everything worked fine. Now when I click on icon (in dock) nothing happens (same with Android Studio in my applications) as if these icons are not clickable.
But i can run studio from `./studio.sh` again.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The symlink of the android studio might be incorrect. Go to your sh file and create its symlink on the desktop. Note : Give the absolute path to your sh file to the icon. Now try and click it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing launcher and try methods described here: [How to add Android Studio to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298857/how-to-add-android-studio-to-the-launcher)

Hope it will help