# How to open Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with Android Studio under Xubuntu.
I downloaded Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) and performed the steps on the site.

When I use Android Studio everything was ok, but when I close the program I can't start it again. I don't have an icon and I don't know how to start the program.

When I run `studio.sh` then applications begins to install Android Studio and downloads android-sdk again.

Comment: Where did you extract the downloaded Android Studio file?

Comment: in /opt folder ...

Comment: At the initial stage, android studio downloads large files like build-tools, HAXM accelerator, emulator etc. You are on the right track running android studio from studio.sh. I think you are losing concentration.

Comment: These two questions can help with running Android Studio and locking it to the launcher: http://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/298857/how-to-add-android-studio-to-the-launcher

Answer (score 0):

> When I run studio.sh then applications begins to install Android Studio and downloads android-sdk again.

It seems that Android Studio is unable to write its own configuration, normally in `.AndroidStudio{version}` folder in your home directory.

Download Android Studio package from: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-stable

let's say to on Desktop and run it using `./bin/studio.sh`.

Check if problem still matters

Also close `Android Studio`, go to your `home` directory, press `CTRL`+`H` to see hidden files and delete `.android` and `.AndroidStudio{version}` folders, they would be recreated on next run