# Android studio is not installing

Tags: android-studio

i tried to install android studio using repository method but when it finished downloading i got this error shown in the image below . Android Studio is saved in /opt folder

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Download Android Studio from this page: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-stable

Unpack the archive and run `studio.sh` in `bin` folder.

There's always a path to create desktop shortcut: [How to add Android Studio to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298857/how-to-add-android-studio-to-the-launcher)

If you need to move this folder to `/opt` folder just use bash commands or  run nautilus with sudo su privillages